# Pandas DataFrame to_json() results in index with dot notation

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that I need to convert to JSON.  The `to_json()` DataFrame method results in an acceptable format, but it converts my DataFrame index to strings (e.g. 0 becomes "0.0").  I need "0".

The DataFrame comes from JSON using the `pd.io.json.read_json()` method, which sets the index to float64.

Input JSON:

```
{"chemical": {"1": "chem2", "0": "chem1"}, 
"type": {"1": "pesticide", "0": "pesticide"}}
```

DataFrame (from `read_json()`):

```
  chemical  type
0 chem1    pesticide
1 chem2    pesticide
```

Produced JSON (from `to_json()`):

```
{"chemical": {"0.0": "chem1", "1.0": "chem2"},
"type": {"0.0": "pesticide", "1.0": "pesticide"}}
```

Needed JSON:

```
{"chemical": {"0": "chem1", "1": "chem2"},
"type": {"0": "pesticide", "1": "pesticide"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@shx2 pointed me in the right direction, but I changed my approach to creating the DataFrame from JSON.

Instead of using the `to_json()` method on a JSON string, I used the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` method on the JSON as a Python dictionary to create the DataFrame.  This results in `df.index.dtype == dtype('O')`

I had to set `dtype='float64'` in the `from_dict()` method to set the correct dtype for the non-string entries.

```
pd_obj = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(request.json["inputs"], dtype='float64')
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the dtype of the index is float (check `df.index.dtype`). You need to convert it to int:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
df.to_json()
=> {"chemical": {"0": "chem1", "1": "chem2"}, "type": {"0": "pesticide", "1": "pesticide"}}
```

Comment: My index is type == float64, and trying to cast it to int throws the following: `TypeError: Setting <class 'pandas.core.index.Float64Index'> dtype to anything other than float64 or object is not supported`

Comment: The `pd.io.json.read_json()` method sets the index to float64, which I didn't mention in my OP.  This causes the `to_json()` method to represent my indexes as floats (e.g 0 -> "0.0").